# Schrodinger equation: Does the operator describe a property of the eigenfunction or is it vice versa?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

What I understand is that we apply an operator, as the Hamiltonian, to a wavefunction of a system to find it's possible and allowed energy values which are the eigenvalues, which are scalar. This wavefunction is called the eigenfunction. When we find that there are more than one eigenfunctions that correspond to the same eigenvalue, then this eigenvalue is degenerate. So I'm just trying to understand the story about how each one acts with the other. But I read that the eigenfunction is used to describe a property of the operator, which is confusing me.

Comment: Let's take the simples example: Orthogonal eigenfunctions. If you use the eigenfunctions as basis, how does the matrix look like?

Answer (score 3):

**Wave function**, $\psi(x)$, describes the state of a quantum mechanical system (like coordinates and momenta $p,q$ describe the state of a classical system). A wave function is not necessarily an eigenfunction of a Hamiltonian or any other operator.

**Operator**, $\hat{O}$, corresponds to a measurable physical quantity. The average obtained in many measurements is then given by acting with the operator on the wave function and integrating the result with the complex conjugate if this wave function:
$$\langle \hat{O}\rangle =\int dx \psi(x)^*\hat{O}\psi(x).$$
Hamiltonian is the operator corresponding to the full energy of the system.

**Eigenfunctions of an operator** are the functions which remain unchanged when the operator acts on them:
$$\hat{O}\psi_\lambda(x)=\lambda \psi_\lambda(x).$$
The coefficient $\lambda$ is called the *eigenvalue.* If more than one eigenfunction correspond to the same eigenvalue, it is called degeneracy.

If the state of the system $\psi(x)$ is an eigenfunction of some operator $\psi_\lambda(x)$ then measuring the corresponding physical quantity will always produce this eigenvalue as the answer.